# Chromium based-browser and vuejs destruction cost

Tags: google-chrome, vuejs2, microsoft-edge

I cope with a problem on a vuejs SPA application. Basically I have a page with a lot of components, and when I click a link that changes the route (either with  or this.$router.push), there's a very slow destroy time, before it reloads the components.

Here is the app structure (it's a grid with rows and cells) :

```
<MainComponent>
    <RowComponent v-for="n">
        <CellComponent v-for="p"></CellComponent>
    </RowComponent>
</MainComponent>
```

The time is not that huge when I have a low number of row, but when I have more than 100 rows, it take ~3 seconds to destroy (I took the measure with the beforeDestroy and destroy), which is the sum of all CellComponent (each component take few milliseconds to destroy).
For example, it take 3 seconds when I have 111 rows and 5 columns (so 555 cells in total).

The thing is that on Brave, Firefox and Safari, it works perfectly and does not take time.
Sometimes, with Chrome and Edge Chromium the problem disappear after few tests but if we restart the browser, the problem comes back.

At first, we thought it was Segment Analytics, but disabling it does not help. I also tried to disable all external services request (with blocking request feature in Chrome). Also the problem.
Then, we try the UBlock extension, and the problem disappeared when the extension was active. We tried a lot of test to identify which setting in UBlock can help, and we found out that it's the "Peter Lowe’s Ad and tracking server list" (https://pgl.yoyo.org/adservers/) setting that solve my problem.

So i can't understand what this setting does more than just blocking request to ads' servers. I tried to block all the requests from "Peter Lowe’s Ad and tracking server list" directly in my /etc/hosts, but I still have the problem on Chrome.

Does someone already dealt with such a problem ?

Comment: What if you run the app in InPrivate window without any extension? Will it be slow in chromium browsers? I didn't find such problem same as yours, only one [which is similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62213505/performance-problems-with-chrome-and-datalist-in-vue-js), you can refer to it. I suggest that you can use F12 dev tools **Network** and **Performance** tab to check which part makes the app slow.

Comment: Hi Yu Zhou, thanks for your answer. Yes I do have the problem in private navigation in Chrome and Edge as well. When I explore with the Performance tab, the time is consumed with $destroy and removeSub functions (the sum of all destruction). Yesterday I tried to remove all Vuex getters and state mapping from my Row and Cell components and I divide the time by 10. So my guess is that in some browser, the reactivity happens before component destroy, and it's this reactivity that takes a lot of time.

Comment: That might be. You can also raise an issue on [vuejs github](https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues) about what you encounter in chromium. This might be an issue of vuejs in chromium browsers.